# Code in faded answer covers over downvote-and-comment box

Tags: bug

Not only is the box faded, it also is *underneath* the code (`<pre></pre>`) formatting.

I have seen other questions like this but I haven't seen this issue yet.

[image]

[Example answer for testing on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27329435/2808510)

[Example answer for testing on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55312/how-to-save-php-file-in-opt-lampp-htdocs-without-going-to-terminal-and-type-sud/510344#510344)

Comment: You realise of course  that "testing" won't work for 2k+ :P

Comment: You realise of course that not everyone has down voting privileges on Ask Ubuntu ;D